# Why the ball is not round?

Tags: reviews, rolling-shutter

Why the ball is not round on following crop:

[image]

SS = `1/60`

What's going on?

Comment: The duplicate explains this as an effect of mechanical rolling shutter. Here, I bet it's because the electronic shutter was used.

Comment: It's not really the same question - this question is "Why is the ball not round" to which the answer is "Because of the rolling shutter effect". The marked duplicate is "What is the rolling shutter effect?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it looks like rolling shutter effect. For more detailed explanation what is this you can check [here](http://www.diyphotography.net/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-rolling-shutter/)

Comment: Rolling shutter at 1/60? What is the sync speed of the camera?

Comment: @MichaelClark, see the effect in video (30 FPS probably): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LVwmtwZLG88 And in photo in question we have movement in opposite directions which make the relative speed much faster

Comment: 30fps does not necessarily equal a shutter speed of 1/30 second. The time the sensor is collecting photons could be much shorter. And the movement here is in the *same* direction. Images projected by the lens are reversed/mirrored on the sensor: the top of the sensor is the bottom of the image and vice versa. Ball is going up and the sensor is reading out from top of sensor/bottom of image to bottom of sensor/top of image.